# Is there a way to quickly find a server with many players on VOIP?

Tags: battlefield-3

I recently bought a new pair of PS3 headphones and wanted to test VOIP yesterday, but to my frustration it was almost impossible to find a server with players using it. On some servers there were 1-2 players with the speaker icon, but they don't speak. I found only one server where everyone (!) was speaking... but in Estonian, or some other weird language - I couldn't even tell which one it was.

So my question is, is there any quick way to find a server with English speaking players using VOIP? Maybe some web site listing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfourtunatley, this is impossible. The only player information provided is who is in there and their scores. There is no indicator denoting whether or not a user is using a headset. The best way to ensure good voice communication is to play with your friends, random players on BF3 are very non-team oriented considering how team oriented the game is...

Comment: To add on, if you do play with randoms and find someone who does talk, play with them for as long as possible, and then send them a friend request - I've added a few people that way who I play with regularly now

Comment: I live in Jersey and on Bad Company 1 I met a kid from Texas that I still play games with today, and he visited last summer hahaha.